# Rewrite taxonomy_term_reference urls to read /taxonomy/term/(name)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, theming

After creating a view to allow /taxonomy/term/(name) to show content tagged with that term, I am trying to find where I can override the generation of field links (field_type_taxonomy_term_reference) so that they create links following this format. Currently they still show the id number for the term at the end. I have tried `(mytheme)_preprocess_taxonomy_term` and altering `$variables['term_url']` but that hasn't worked. Can anyone please give me any pointers about how to do this, I am running out of ideas.

Any thoughts welcome.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: My answer here might be useful: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18784/how-to-modify-taxonomy-term-path-in-the-page-render-array/48661#48661

Comment: That is indeed useful! We gave up on taxonomy in the end though, not needed for what we were doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set URL aliases for your taxonomy terms using the Path module that comes with Drupal core. (EDIT: As mentioned by jordojuice, you'll also need the Pathauto module to automatically generate these patterns in the manner I instruct below).

1. Go to the Configuration menu and select "Url Aliases" in the "Search and Metadata" section. (admin/config/search/path)
2. In the upper tab of the URL Aliases menu, select "Patterns." Here you can set the path to your taxonomy terms to whatever you'd like.

The only problem is that I don't think Views overwrites the URLs generated. There was [a module for this](http://drupal.org/project/views_tpo) in Drupal 6, but I don't think there is anything similar for D7.

There is a View that comes default in Views that should overwrite the default taxonomy paths; you could see what it does and try to tweak it.

Comment: If you end up working with URL aliases (a great feature) you should definitely check out [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) as well.

Comment: This is useful but it is not what I was after. I may have to just hack core instead - changing 1 line does what I want. Surely it can't be this hard to overwrite in a better, standards orientated way?